# what is the best to control the call of APIs in play framework

Tags: playframework, guava, playframework-2.2, playframework-2.3, playframework-2.5

I use play framework need to implement the following mechanism for the users:

**1.Limit the max number of API calls such as 100 times for a user. For example, User A is 100 times. B user is 1000 times.**

**2.Control the grant of APIs such as for API getWeatherByCity(string city); User A is granted this API. User B can't call this API.**

**3.Control the number of API calls per day per user.**

Can Guava support all of the 3 scenarios? Is there example for each of the above scenarios?

Or is there any better way to implement this in play framework?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the ActionCreator or the GlobalSetting to limit your request.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaActionCreator

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaGlobal

Add the authentication code inside the GlobalSetting's onRequest method or create an ActionCreator to handle your request base on Logged in User.